# Manipulating arrays: Inserting new element to a certain index and shifting other elements

Tags: arrays, perl, splice

I have an array say

`my @array = (1,4,5,8);`

Each element of above array may or may not have a child.

Suppose 1 has 2,3 as children and 5 has 10 as a child.

I have to manipulate array such that it becomes `1,2,3,4,5,10,8`

---

What I'm doing at current

```
foreach (@$children_indexes){ #myarray
        foreach ($self->{RELATION}[$_]->{CHILDREN}){ #find the child of each index
            push @$children_indexes, @$_; #I need to change this, as this is pushing at the end
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `$self->{RELATION}[$_]->{CHILDREN}` is an arrayref?

Either loop through your array of indexes by index and backwards:

```
for my $index_index ( reverse 0..$#$children_indexes ) {
    if ( $self->{RELATION}[$children_indexes->[$index_index]]{CHILDREN} ) {
        splice @$children_indexes, $index_index+1, 0, @{ $self->{RELATION}[$children_indexes->[$index_index]]{CHILDREN} };
    }
}
```

or use map:

```
my @array_with_children = map { $_, @{ $self->{RELATION}[$_]{CHILDREN} || [] } } @$children_indexes;
```

(both assume ...->{CHILDREN} will be nonexist, or false at any rate, if no children)

Comment: When I used it like this. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bvPfmkbd I get the error saying: Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference. I've put the code in IF block which already checks for defined.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps just use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( 1, 4, 5, 8 );

my %children = (
    1 => [ 2, 3 ],
    5 => [ 10 ],
);

my @new_array = map { ($_, @{ $children{$_} // [] }) } @array;

print "@new_array\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 10 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't see why he should be using map this can be done perfectly fine with arrays.

With this you can get the index of the current element in your loop to see where you are adding:

```
my @array = qw(A B C E F G);
my $search = "C";

my %index;
@index{@array} = (0..$#array); 
my $index = $index{$search}; < - getting the index of the curr element
print $index, "\n";

my @out_array;
my $insert = 'D'; 

push @out_array,
        @array[0..$index],
        $insert,
        @array[$index+1..$#array];

print @array;
print "\n";
print @out_array;
```

Here is a working example of how this can be done :).

Comment: True that. But since he was asking for arrays and the only answear was "use map" .. :D I though it would be better to atlest give example how else it can be done ( though it's more complicated )